# GitLab CI. Job failed with error: ERROR: Job failed: exit status 9009

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to set up GitLab Runner on a Windows 10 machine to build Private projects.

The build fails when the script comes to python-related commands, or minGW32-make with a similar output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.2.1 (32fc1585)
  on NewBuildServer GhcDD9Gz
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on RND_SBORKA2NEW...
DEPRECATION: CMD shell is deprecated and will no longer be supported
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/GhcDD9Gz/0/shirobokov/ramenkap_test_runners/.git/
Checking out c814ddda as master...
Updating/initializing submodules recursively with git depth set to 50...
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ echo "Build begin"
"Build begin"
$ cd project
$ python tools/prebuild.py settings.mak
"python" �� ����� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� �������� 䠩���.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 9009
```

At the same time, locally, the project is assembled without problems. mingw32 and python are added to PATH.
How to solve the problem with incorrect output:

```
"python" �� ����� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� �������� 䠩���.
```

In the GitLab Runner settings, "cmd" is selected as the "executor". What is the difference between executing the same commands locally and in GitLab?

```
[[runners]]
  name = "NewBuildServer"
  url = "https://XXXXX.YY.ZZ/"
  token = "GhcDD9GzDypuJxLJgBLq"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "cmd"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved as follows:
The build on the GitLab Runner server was successful, because the PATH variables were registered for the current user(User variables for).

GitLab uses "System variables" that were not registered on the server where GitLab Runner was installed.

It is necessary to add all the necessary PATHs to the "System variables"